# How can I sort two arrays in descending order?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to write a program that asks the user to enter the number of pancakes eaten for breakfast by 10 different people (Person 1, Person 2, ..., Person 10).

I need to modify the program so that it outputs a list in order of number of pancakes eaten of all 10 people.

Example:

```
Person 4: ate 10 pancakes
Person 3: ate 7 pancakes
Person 8: ate 4 pancakes
...
Person 5: ate 0 pancakes
```

I have been able to sort the number of pancakes into descending order, however I am struggling to assign the correct `Person` to their number of pancakes.

Here is my code so far:

```
int main()
{
    int person[10];
    int i;
    int input;
    int n = sizeof(person) / sizeof(person[0]);

    // store the number entered by the user in each array element
    for(i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        cout << "How many pancakes did Person " << i + 1 << " eat? ";
        cin >> person[i];
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    sort(person, person + n, greater<int>()); // sorts array in descending order. "greater()" puts larger numbers first
    
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        cout << "Person " << i + 1 << " ate " << person[i] << " pancakes." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: 1) Use `<vector>`, not C arrays. 2) Check `std::sort`.

Comment: combine the person and pancake count into one struct, then sort an array of those structs

Comment: Alternatively to @DevSolar, you could use `std::array` as well, since you have pre-defined the size.

Comment: There are two ways: apply the same moves to the elements of the pancakes and persons arrays, or sort through an index (array of integers that points at the array elements in sorted order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `std::vector` of `std::pair` to store the Person index and its corresponding value. Then, you can use a comparator function to sort by values.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<pair<int, int>> person(10);

    // store the number entered by the user in each array element
    for(int i = 0; i < person.size(); ++i)
    {
        person[i].first = i + 1;
        cout << "How many pancakes did Person " << i + 1 << " eat? ";
        cin >> person[i].second;
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    auto compare = [](const pair<int, int>& a, const pair<int, int>& b)
    {
        return a.second > b.second;
    };

    sort(person.begin(), person.end(), compare); 

    for(int i = 0; i < person.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Person " << person[i].first << " ate " << person[i].second << " pancakes." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

You can also encapsulate the person details in a `struct` and use that `struct` with `std::vector`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

struct Person
{
    int index;
    int pancakesEaten;
};

int main()
{
    vector<Person> person(10);

    // store the number entered by the user in each array element
    for(int i = 0; i < person.size(); ++i)
    {
        person[i].index = i + 1;
        cout << "How many pancakes did Person " << i + 1 << " eat? ";
        cin >> person[i].pancakesEaten;
    }

    cout << endl;
    cout << endl;

    auto compare = [](const Person& a, const Person& b)
    {
        return a.pancakesEaten > b.pancakesEaten;
    };

    sort(person.begin(), person.end(), compare); 

    for(int i = 0; i < person.size(); i++)
    {
        cout << "Person " << person[i].index << " ate " << person[i].pancakesEaten << " pancakes." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::pair` can also be replaced by named struct to have better naming

Comment: @Jarod42, yes made the edits.

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of the sorting of the std::map.

```
int main()
{
    constexpr int person_num = 10;

    multimap<int, int, greater<>> pancakes_person_pairs;

    for (int i = 0; i < person_num; ++i)
    {
        int cur_person = i + 1;
        cout << "How many pancakes did Person " << cur_person << " eat? ";
        unsigned int cur_pancakes;
        cin >> cur_pancakes;
        pancakes_person_pairs.insert(make_pair(cur_pancakes, cur_person));
    }

    cout << endl << endl;

    for (const auto& pancakes_person_pair : pancakes_person_pairs)
    {
        cout << "Person " << pancakes_person_pair.second << " ate " << pancakes_person_pair.first << " pancakes." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use indirection. Set up an array of indices 0 to n and sort that index array by defering the comparison to the count array:

```
vector<int> ind(n);
iota(ind.begin(), ind.end(), 0);  // #include <numeric>

sort(ind.begin(), ind.end(),
    [&](int a, int b) { return person[a] > person[b]; });

for (int i : ind) {
    cout << "Person " << i + 1 << " ate " << person[i] << " pancakes." << endl;
    }
}
```